# Does LDAP work in an ActiveDirectory environment?

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm working on an independent java application inside an Active Directory environment and the usual way for authentication is SingleSignOn.
But there I have some interfaces, which is not supporting SSO. And now I'm thinking of using LDAP for authenticate Users for the applications.

My question is: is it possible to implement LDAP inside an ActiveDirectory environment?

- If yes: how does it work together and what do I have to do exactly?
- If no: are there any other alternatives except for SSO?

Comment: I think your question is too broad. We help with specific programming questions, not with requests to design a solution/vision.

Comment: I think I'm hoping for any inspiration or explenations about this topic..

Comment: I understand that. But "inspiration" and "broad explanations" aren't exactly on topic here.

Comment: I see. only programming questions. got it ^^

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory Domain Controllers function as LDAP servers. Servers will have clear-text LDAP bound on port 389, and servers that can auto-enroll for a certificate will have ssl encrypted LDAP bound on port 636.

Active Directory as an LDAP server is *basically* like any other LDAP server, BUT the schema names change. Where you would normally see uid in LDAP, Microsoft uses sAMAccountName or userPrincipalName. The domain is based on domain components (dc=something) instead of organizations (o=something). But the basic concepts remain the same.

You can look at the SRV record for the domain to return a list of candidate domain controllers to use as the LDAP server, you can configure a load balancer VIP to front the directory and add domain controllers that are intended to handle LDAP-sourced authentication traffic, or you can have a primary ldap host with a secondary host to use if that one fails to connect.

If you are using LDAP-SSL (and that's the right thing to do), you'll need to add the public key(s) for the CA chain to the cacerts file unless the domain admins have gone through the process of getting DC certs signed by a public CA. Connect to the AD servers via LDAP, bind with system creds, search for user -- something like (&(sAMAccountName=WhatUserEntered)) -- at the base DN for the organization, return the object fully qualified DN, bind with the fully qualified DN and the password the user provided. Check the result code to determine if authentication passed.

Comment: OK, so I just misunderstood the whole concept about LDAP and SSO. thank you for your help.